# Skip one subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I want to create subfigs like this. The first image in the second row is skipped (also the numbering) and images are vertically aligned. Could someone help for this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows us what you have tried. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and suggest what might work when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Note that the `mwe` package includes sample images you can use if you wish (you don't need to load the package - you can just say, e.g., `\includegraphics{example-image-a}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would provide a basic layout of the kind you show in your question. It uses the `subfig` package to layout multiple sub-figures within one larger `figure` environment. To get the lower row to align with the right of the upper row, some horizontal spacing is added at the beginning of the row to shift everything right by the equivalent of one sub-figure's width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig, graphicx}
\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

      \hspace*{.2\textwidth}\quad
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

      \caption{Optional caption}\label{fig:myfigure}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sub-figures with uneven alignment]